# Is there a layout view that automatically fits the UI to the user's screen size in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, user-interface

In Android Studio, is there an XML layout that will automatically adjust (shrink/enlarge) the view contents User Interface to fit on one single screen of varying sizes (i.e. different smartphones, tablets, etc.) as opposed to using a combination of LinearLayout and ScrollView in order to stack every UI component on top of one another?

I usually just do the latter but was just curious if there is a layout out there that automatically detects the user's screen size and shrinks/enlarges the view contents accordingly.

Comment: you need an AI layout to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Answer is No

You have to define dimension or layout file for different screen size.

[Designing for Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

you should Use  layout_weight property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout's weightSum and layout_weight components. For details check:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#getWeightSum()

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised, nobody mentioned `ConstraintLayout`

[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) is a ViewGroup which allows you to position and size widgets in a flexible way.

ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

View [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)